# How to remove transform effects from future processing lines in Processing.js

Tags: processing.js

I apologize in advance if the answer to this question is somewhere on this site. I am new to this and if the answer is on stack overflow the main reason why I couldn't find it is because I don't know the correct termanology.

I have a very simple project in class which is to make an animal in processing.js.

My problem being is that with the transform "lines" it stacks. Say you have two transform lines they multiply or stack.

```js
noFill();
scale(2, 2);
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
scale(3, 3);
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

```html
<script src="http://processing.js"></script>
```

The first rectangle will be double the size and the second rectangle will be 6x the size. What's intended ( for me ) is to have the second rectangle not 6x the size but 3x the size. I know I could just scale it a lower number but this gets pretty tricky when I have 5 different objects scaled and it also stacks for rotation, referencing to the last rotational point. If anyone knows a line that would seperate it as a different object or remove the stacking as if it were on the "top(lowest number in lines) of the code it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. If you would like the code for my project just ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
The problem with your code (as you already know) is that transform (matrix) operations (translates, rotations, and scales) stack (add together). They are actually matrices that are multiplied together (linear algebra).

To fix your problem what you want to do is to call pushMatrix() before your transforms, do your transforms, draw your rects or ellipses or whatever, and then call popMatrix().

pushMatrix (http://processingjs.org/reference/pushMatrix_/) saves (pushes) the current transform matrix onto the stack, i.e. saves it so you can get it back later.

popMatrix() (http://processingjs.org/reference/popMatrix_/) discards the current transform (pops it) and gets the old matrix transform back off of the stack, i.e. resets the transform.

So your code would look like this:

```
noFill();
pushMatrix(); // save current transform (no transform)
    scale(2, 2);
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
popMatrix(); // get old transform back (no transform)
pushMatrix();
    scale(3, 3);
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
popMatrix();
```

Feel free to ask any more questions you may have.

Also check out the processing js documentation. You might find it helpful: http://processingjs.org/reference/


**Edit**

You could also call resetMatrix() (http://processingjs.org/reference/resetMatrix_/) as well because you just want to revert the transform to no transform.

```
noFill();
    scale(2, 2);
rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
resetMatrix();//reset transform, i.e. erase the scale
    scale(3, 3);
rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for the help! This'll make it much easier and I won't have to adjust it every time.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. If you think my answer is best, would you mind accepting it ;).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for the `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions. More info can be found in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/), but basically it would look like this:

```
pushMatrix();
scale(2, 2);
rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
popMatrix();

pushMatrix();
scale(3, 3);
rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
popMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the popMatrix()/resetMatrix() is probably your best choice, but with some math, you could not have to do that (but it is still is probably your best choice).

So given this:

```
pushMatrix();
scale(a, a);
rect(x, y, w, h);
scale(b, b);
rect(x, y, w, h);
popMatrix();
```

If you wnt the second rectangle to be drawn at the scale of b, and not want the scaling to be stacked, you could do:

```
…
scale(a/b, a/b);
…
```

a represents the scale factor of the first scale, andd b represents the size you want your scaled shape compared to your originaal size.
In your case, a = 2, and b = 3.
So,

```
…
scale(2, 2);
…
scale(3/2, 3/2);
rect(x, y, w, h);
```

The rectangle will be the same if scaled in another pushMatrix().
But you probably still want to stick with popMatrix() and resetMatrix().